# Swift - Initializing model object with properties across multiple views

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, properties, model

A client wants me to initialize a model object, but the issue I'm facing is that the properties I need are located across five view controllers. At view controller 1 I define propertyA for my object. View controller 2 I define propertyB, and so on. On the final view I get to see a summary of what i've chosen and from there I can finally create my object.

I'm doing this incredibly long and inefficient at the moment where I have the same optional variables for each property across many views. Any help would be great.

Comment: What kind of data are we talking? It sounds like you could get away with some kind of manager class that is either a singleton or retained by some class that outlives all the views so all the views' view models can modify the same instance.

Comment: Do all views need the properties? If so, why don't you have a baseclass? I find your question not specific enough and it therefore seems it's about code structure basics.

Comment: @Dare It's just Strings, Int's and Doubles. I'm about to take your advice on a manager. The approach I might take is to try create a class with optional properties that match my model and update them via singletons. Would that work?

Comment: @meaning-matters You're correct. I didn't explain it the best I could have. There are five view controllers, each allowing the user to select and define some data which will be used to create a model object in the final view controller. I'm working with an app that has it's UI and VC's laid out and it's flow is really bad. I created a base class first but was told by my client to work with the views that they already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this scenario you should try Singleton pattern

1. Create class having all properties and create its singleton also:

   ```
   public class Property {
       public var propertyA:AnyObject? /// define your appropriate data type
       public  var propertyB:AnyObject?
       public var propertyC:AnyObject?
       public var propertyD:AnyObject?
       public var propertyE:AnyObject?
       static let sharedInstance = Property()
   }
   ```
2. To Set Values in different-2 view controller follow below pattern. Here I am assuming that you can set property any place in view controller. For now I am considering to `viewDidLoad` you can change value to any part of view controller

   ```
   class ViewController1: UIViewController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           Property.sharedInstance.propertyA = "X" as AnyObject //// Value should be of same data type of propertyA
       }
   }

   class ViewController2: UIViewController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           Property.sharedInstance.propertyB = "Y" as AnyObject //// Value should be of same data type of propertyA
       }
   }
   ```

   etc
3. finally at the end you will get values of all assigned parameters

   ```
   print(Property.sharedInstance.propertyA)
   print(Property.sharedInstance.propertyB)
   print(Property.sharedInstance.propertyC)
   print(Property.sharedInstance.propertyD)
   print(Property.sharedInstance.propertyE)
   ```

Comment: @rob and jeetendra I'll give it a shot! But I do have a question about the 1. **What is the reason behind using public classes and public variables?** I assumed singletons allowed accessibility with or without public access.

Comment: If your project have multiple modules or project dependencies and you want to access from any other module (except its own module) then without public you can not access class and its properties. If Single Module in project no need of public

Comment: This will work Single Module Project .                                                        class Property {
    var propertyA:AnyObject?
    var propertyB:AnyObject?
    var propertyC:AnyObject?
    var propertyD:AnyObject?
    var propertyE:AnyObject?
    static let sharedInstance = Property()
}

Comment: Module means xcodeproj file and contents as child project

Comment: @Breezy - I don't deserve any credit here; I only edited the formatting of the answer. In fact, I'm not an advocate of singletons for model objects. The singleton pattern is super simple, but it's not scalable (classes are tightly coupled, writing good tests is harder, it's hard to identify where model is being modified, etc.). While it's a little more complicated, I'd personally lean towards dependency injection pattern. See [Improving Existing Apps with Modern Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/213/?time=1146).